# Extract data from sample sheet with another sheet telling what factor to multiply the data and when to extract

Tags: excel, vba, extract, paste, timeline

I have three source sheets that show expected performance of three types of cities for 24 months (Small, Medium and Large).

Typical view - this tab's called small city sample.
[image: this]

I have a 'city launch' sheet. Essentially it is a matrix that shows a timeline of possible city launches, and amount of specific city launches in a month (factor + timeline spreading of sample sheet).
[image: this]

For example. Jan-20 2 small cities in country A, 1 large city in country A, 1 medium city in Country B etc, with a total (sumifs) at the top.

I'm trying to figure out a macro that based on the amount of 'cities' launched in the specific month (from city launch tab), extracts from city tabs, multiples by the factors, then spreads and adds preceding data in to the consolidated tab. 
[image: tab]

The data in [image: these sample city tabs] is static, as they are the base.

The consolidated tab is essentially a detailed version of sample city tabs where the 'levers' are essentially in [image: this].

How could I attempt this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at writing a function in the Consolidated tab which takes in the "small", "medium" and "large" tables as arguments and then takes the city/size as an argument too. Then use the city/size argument to look at the relevant small/medium/large table and iterate over the headers to find the correct factor then carry out your arithmetic in the function

Comment: Thank you for your time on this! I've broken it down in to the following steps: 1) Check how many cities starting in the month 2) copy data from city tab 3) Multiply by how many starting from (1) 4) Paste in consolidated 5) Check how many cities starting next month 6) Copy data from city tab 7) Multiply by how many starting from (5) 8) Paste in the new month in consolidated tab in a way that also adds data from preceding month